# Edit text expand on click

Tags: android, animation, web, webview, android-edittext

I have a edittext that needs to expand to the full width of the app when typing, when clicked outside or anywhere else it goes back to regular size.
i have found a piece of code that does work for what i want but it doesn't hold such as it reverses the process once the end of the code has run. Im looking for a way around this.Or another way to do this, a similar example to this is when using a web browser on a mobile device, when typing a url or search term the url bar expands to full width.

**Home Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText search_bar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


   search_bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    }
    public void edit_clicked(View view){

    Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 2, 1, 2);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
    search_bar.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain it better? You want the edit text to resize back to the initial size after you insert the text or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dynamic way of doing this:**

```
   ScaleAnimation animate = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
    animate.setDuration(700);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    target.startAnimation(animate);
```

**Way of Using XML**

scale.xml (Put this in res/anim folder)

```
    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fillAfter="true"        
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

**Java code**

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Anims.this, R.anim.scale);
mEdittext.startAnimation(anim);
```

**(or)**

Simple try this

```
Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    editText.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly, is there a way to when not using the edit text it undoes

Comment: The Animation anim, works perfectly but what would the code be to undue when anywhere outside of the Edittext is touched or clicked